# SQL Server : inserting date returning wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to insert information from another table, it is returning '1900-01-01' from a `date` column when it should be empty. On the import table the datatype is `varchar` and on the table I want to insert the information into it is a `date` datatype. There are some empty values in the `EndDate` column that should be inserted as empty but it is returning '1900-01-01'

```
Insert into tblServiceHistory (PersonID, PositionID, CommitteeID,StartDate, EndDate)
    Select distinct 
        PersonID, PositionID, CommitteeID, StartDate, EndDate
    From 
        tblCommitteeOfficers_IMPORT 
    Where 
        PersonID is not null
        And StartDate is not null
        And PositionID is not null
        And CommitteeID is not null
```

Comment: You would appear to have the value `1900-01-01` in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank strings converted to dates turn in to `'1900-01-01'`.

e.g. `select convert(date,'')` returns `'1900-01-01'`.

You can use [**`nullif()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to turn empty strings into `null` values in your `select`.

Try this:

```
Insert into tblServiceHistory (PersonID, PositionID, CommitteeID,StartDate, EndDate)
Select distinct PersonID, PositionID, CommitteeID, nullif(StartDate,''), nullif(EndDate,'')
From tblCommitteeOfficers_IMPORT 
Where PersonID is not null
  AND nullif(StartDate,'') is not null
  AND PositionID is not null
  AND CommitteeID is not null
```